# Looping in SQL with TempTable

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am new to SQL Server, can you please help me to write query for my scenario?

I have this `Table1` :

```
PostingDate     ReturnCheckReason   PaymentStatus   PolicyNumber
----------------------------------------------------------------
7/23/2020 15:30 Null                    Payment         1234
8/6/2020 17:40  Null                    Payment         1234
8/4/2020 14:29  Null                    Payment         1234
8/5/2020 6:09   Null                    Payment         1234
8/5/2020 12:47  Cancel Payment          Return          1234
```

Input to my stored procedure is a `PolicyNumber` e.g 1234 and the code should return 5 rows.

I need to cover these cases:

1. If the first payment is not cancelled, I need return that row.
2. If the first payment is cancelled, look for a next non-cancelled payment. If a next payment is found that was not cancelled, I need to return that row.

My question is: I think I need to loop all the data for that policy till I get a non-cancelled payment, please let me know how do I that.

```
SELECT TOP 1
    [PolicyNumber],
    [PostingDate],
    [PaymentStatus]
FROM 
    [dbo].[Bil_PaymentSearch] WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE 
    (PolicyNumber = @PolicyNumber) AND
    (ReturnCheckreason <> 'Cancel payment') AND 
    (PaymentOrReturn <> 'Return')
ORDER BY 
    PostingDate ASC
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to take `NULL`s into account:

```
SELECT TOP 1 [PolicyNumber], [PostingDate], [PaymentStatus]
FROM [dbo].[Bil_PaymentSearch]
WHERE PolicyNumber = @PolicyNumber AND
      (ReturnCheckreason <> 'Cancel payment' OR ReturnCheckreason IS NULL) AND 
      PaymentOrReturn <> 'Return'
ORDER BY PostingDate ASC
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon for your quick response. However the problem with this approach what if 1st and 2nd row has ReturnCheckReason as 'Cancel Payment' then do I need to loop using while or still this query works ?

Comment: Please let me know does your query handle these two cases : - If the first payment is not cancelled , I need return that row.
If the first payment is cancelled , look for a next non-cancelled payment. If a next payment is found that was not cancelled, I need to return that row.

Comment: @Shankar . .. This returns the first row, based on the `postingdate` that matches the `where` conditions.  No additional looping is needed.

Comment: Thanks again, last question.  So in that case my both the two conditions will satisfy correct ? (1)If the first payment is not cancelled , I need return that row. (2) If the first payment is cancelled , look for a next non-cancelled payment. If a next payment is found that was not cancelled,I need to return that row.

Comment: @Shankar . . . Yes, that it what it does.

Comment: Hi Gordon, There is one problem with my query - At present my qurey return as NULL, If all the Payment are Cancelled for that Policy. like I need to return back as "All Payments are Cancelled" in the "PaymentStatus" Column

Comment: Please advise me How do I do that ?